# Python pandas group by filter records as per logic

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the pandas dataframe:
[image]

From it, i need pick all the resources based on below logic:

1. Resources who are with Status as "Accept" for multiple Company
2. Resources who are with Status as "Accept" for multiple Role

Expected output: [image]

Comment: Share data not pics

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
#create dataframe
d = [['T1','A','Engineer','accept'],['T2','B','Doctor','accept'],['T2','A','Engineer','Reject'],['T1','A','Engineer','Reject']]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df.columns = ['Resource','Company','Role','Status']
df_= df.loc[df['Status']=="accept",]

#group by 2 columns
df_.groupby(['Resource'])['Role','Company'].nunique().add_prefix('num_').reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not how the expected output is. It should have all the Resources in Pandas DF. ( as shown in the expected output )